# Java indexOf method for multiple matches in String

Tags: java, indexof

I had a question about the indexOf method. I want to find multiple cases of "X" in a string.

Suppose my string is "x is x is x is x", I want to find x in all of its index positions.
But how do you do this for multiple cases? Is this even possible with indexOf?

I did int temp = str.indexOf('x');
It find the first x. I tried to do a for loop where i is initialized to length of string and this did not work since I kept finding the first x over and over.

```
for (int y = temp1; y >= 0;y-- ) 
{
    int temp = str.indexOf('x');
    System.out.println(temp);
}
```

But this does not work. Am I supposed to use regex? Because I don't really know how to use regex method.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

There is a second variant of the `indexOf` method, which takes a start-index as a parameter.

```
i = str.indexOf('x');
while(i >= 0) {
     System.out.println(i);
     i = str.indexOf('x', i+1);
}
```

Comment: Ah, thank you very much everyone. That makes a lot of sense since you just iterate through the string based on position of last match.

Answer (score 12):

There's a another version of `indexOf` method, taking `fromIndex` as parameter.
So, you can call it in a loop, each time passing `prevPosition + 1` as a second parameter.

Documentation:
[http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int, int)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int,%20int%29)

Answer (score 5):

You can specify the start index with [indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int,%20int%29). So, in your loop you store the last position of 'x', then search again using that index + 1.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution with Streams API :

```java
String text = "Lets search for E ?";

final char key = 'e';
int[] indices = IntStream.range(0, text.length())
    .filter(i -> text.charAt(i) == key)
    .toArray();
```

Output will be like this :

```java
//1
//6
```

If you want to add upper case letters into your result, you need to change the `filter`'s argument closure with :

```java
.filter(i -> Character.toLowerCase(text.charAt(i)) == key)
```

Then the output will be like this :

```
//1
//6
//16
```

Additionally if you just want to use the results or print it out for quick testing purposes you can do it with using `forEach` terminal operation:

```java
IntStream.range(0, text.length())
    .filter(i -> text.charAt(i) == key)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String name = "alameer kaiser aziz";
String found = "a";
int num = name.indexOf(found);
while (num >=0) {
    System.out.println(num);
    num = name.indexOf(found,num+1);
}
```