# Differences between contains and indexOf, Java

Tags: java, string, if-statement, replace, substring

I am doing the following programming exercise: [The old switcheroo](https://www.codewars.com/kata/55d410c492e6ed767000004f). The statement is:

> Write a function
>
> `Kata.Vowel2Index("this is my string") == "th3s 6s my str15ng"`
>
> `Kata.Vowel2Index("Codewars is the best site in the world") == "C2d4w6rs 10s th15 b18st s23t25 27n th32 w35rld"`
>
> Your function should be case insensitive to the vowels.

I have doubts when the input is an empty string, I mean when we test with:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class KataTest {
  @Test public void test4() {
    assertEquals("", Kata.vowel2Index(""));
  }
  
}
```

My question is, why if we use contains, we have to check if input string is empty?

```
import java.util.*;
public class Kata {
  static final String VOWELS = "AEIOUaeiou";
  public static String vowel2Index/*➡️*/(String s) {
    if(s==null || s.equals("")) return "";
    String[] letters = s.split("");
    
    for(int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++){
      if(VOWELS.contains(letters[i])){
        letters[i] = String.valueOf(i+1);
      }
    }
    return String.join("",letters);
  }
}
```

Or check if the current string inside the loop is empty:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Kata {
  static final String VOWELS = "AEIOUaeiou";
  public static String vowel2Index/*➡️*/(String s) {
    String[] letters = s.split("");
    
    for(int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++){
      if(letters[i] != "" && VOWELS.contains(letters[i])){
        letters[i] = String.valueOf(i+1);
      }
    }
    return String.join("",letters);
  }
}
```

But we can omit the previous condition when we use indexOf:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Kata {
  static final String VOWELS = "AEIOUaeiou";
  public static String vowel2Index/*➡️*/(String s) {
    String[] letters = s.split("");
    
    for(int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++){
      if(VOWELS.indexOf(letters[i]) > 0){
        letters[i] = String.valueOf(i+1);
      }
    }
    return String.join("",letters);
  }
}
```

I have also read:

- [How to check if a String contains another String in a case insensitive manner in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86780/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-another-string-in-a-case-insensitive-manner-in)
- [Java indexOf method for multiple matches in String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988050/java-indexof-method-for-multiple-matches-in-string)

What are the differences between contains and indexOf?‽?

Comment: One returns a boolean, the other an int, just that. depends on the need

Comment: `contains` is simply `return indexOf(s.toString()) > -1;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
contains()
```

It is a common case in programming when you want to check if specific String contains a particular substring. For example, If you want to test if the String "The big red fox" contains the substring "red." This method is useful in such situation.

```
    String s1 = "My name is bar"; 
    System.out.println(s1.contains("bar")); 
    System.out.println(s1.contains("foo")); 

    //output
    true
    false
```

2..

```
indexOf()
```

This method returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified character or -1, if the character does not occur.

```
    String gfg = new String("Welcome to stackoverflow"); 
    System.out.print("Found s first at position : ");  
    System.out.println(gfg.indexOf('s'));

   //output
   Found s first at position : 11
```

Answer (score 1):

`contains` and `indexOf` behave exactly the same, they have the same runtime. `contains` is defined as `indexOf(s.toString()) > -1`.
In the corner case of an empty string `""` as input to the methods they behave in a way you obviously do not expect: They return `0` / `true`. That means that your statements

```
VOWELS.contains(letters[i])
letters[i] != "" && VOWELS.contains(letters[i])
VOWELS.indexOf(letters[i]) > 0
```

simply do different things and are not equivalent.

For `""` they are `true`, `false`, `false`.
For `"A"` they are `true`, `true`, `false`.
For `"B"` they are `true`, `true`, `true`.

Comment: `indexOf(x) > 0` is *not* the same as `contains(x)`. I know it's a copy/paste error from the question, but you already showed the correct code, i.e. `indexOf(x) > -1`, or alternatively `indexOf(x) >= 0`.

Comment: You don't actually say that anywhere, you don't explain why `"A"` behaves badly. --- Also, `letters[i] != ""` is bad code, since you can't use `!=` to compare strings.

Answer (score 0):

`indexOf` will return an Integer with the index where the substring beginns and -1 when the substring does not appear.

`contains` will return a boolean wether it contains the substring or not.

Comment: No, `contains` cannot be faster since it simply calls `indexOf`.

Comment: Just double checked - and you are right - I will update my answer.
Back then, when the test was done it seemed that two different algorithms were used,